# Deleting href when clicked on a link (a delete icon) beside it (Javascript help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link `<a href="#">` and beside that there is a delete png icon (which is also `<a href="#">`  link.
So what I want is, when clicked on that delete icon, the link `<a href="#">` should get deleted with a confirmation window.

So far I have got like,
html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link</a> <a class="delete" href="#" data-request="POST" >....</a></li>
</ul>
```

My javascript for `data-request`

```
var join_request = function(evnt){
     evnt.preventDefault();
     var $a = $(this);
     var request = $a.data('request') || 'POST';
     if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete it?")) {
        $.ajax($a.attr('href'), {
         type: request,
         context: $a,
         success: join_request_success
     });
     }
     return false;
 };

 var join_request_success = function(data, a, b){
     this.trigger('executed');
 }; 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[data-request]').bind('click', join_request);
 }
```

This doesn't seem to be working! When I am clicking on the delete icon, it is displaying the confirmation window but not doing anything.

Is there any other simple way of achieving this? If not, can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is this event "executed". what is happening there. Please add more code or create fiddle.

Comment: What is the URL you are going to hit using AJAX ??? it is seems to "#" ???

Comment: @JitendraKhatri thats a link of delete() method in controllers. Instead of writing the whole link, I have just used "#"

Comment: @Sandeeproop Sorry! I think creating fiddle is not possible in this scenario because the delete class uses the link (href) from controllers

Answer (score 0):

```js
var join_request = function(evnt){
  evnt.preventDefault();
  var $a = $(this);
  var request = $a.data('request') || 'POST';
  if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete it?")) {
    $.ajax($a.attr('href'), {
      type: request,
      context: $a,
      error: join_request_success
    });
  }
  return false;
};

var join_request_success = function(data, a, b){
  this.trigger('executed');
  this.prev().remove();
}; 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[data-request]').bind('click', join_request);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link</a> <a class="delete" href="#" data-request="POST" >....</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that I had to change `success:` to `error:` for demonstration.

Comment: Okay this is deleting the link, but however it is reappearing again when I am refreshing the page. I want it to not appear even when I refresh! What could be the issue?

Comment: There has to be some condition you could check to display or not display it. What is this deleting? Could you check, on page load, if it's been deleted? Etc...

Comment: Sorry how to check it?

Comment: Check what? I barely know what you're trying to do. I assume the ajax is sending a server call to delete something. Why is it still showing when the page refreshes? Are you not actually deleting it? Etc. etc.